# Create a binary column by searching if a string appears in a text or not

Tags: r

I have a data frame that has 4 columns and one of them contains texts(Engi_log) actually comments if no paragraphs. what I want is to create a particular column that marks 1 if a particular word appears in there or 0 if not.
I used the code below but it still does not work:

```
  library(dplyr)
 output <- mydata %>%
 dplyr::mutate(
player_mike = ifelse(Engi_log == "redo", 1, 0)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `==`. You need `grepl`. Also no `ifelse` needed, i.e.

```
...mutate(player_mike = as.integer(grepl('redo', Engi_log)))
```

As @Gregor notes, we do not need to go through the regex engine of `grepl` so adding `fixed = TRUE` in `grepl` will improve efficiency

Comment: Recommend `fixed = TRUE` for `grepl` since no regex is needed.

Comment: I always forget the fixed part. Thanks :)

Comment: Improving efficiency is good, but another great reason to use `fixed = TRUE` is preventing bugs, especially for users unfamiliar with regex. If OP's next search happens to contain a special character, they could be very confused.